# Android - RecyclerView to RecyclerViewFragment

Tags: android

I am trying to create a ListView in a Fragment within a ViewPager in a AppCompatActivity. In the AppCompatActivity are all view elements are wrappend in a CoordinatorLayout. Because I used the CoordinatorLayout. I have to use a RecylerView I am trying to follow the training from developer.android.com. Is it possible to change this RecyclerView code to RecyclerViewFragment code ? If it's possible, please help me to change it.

Thanks

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class AdapterFish extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    List<DataFish> data= Collections.emptyList();
    DataFish current;
    int currentPos=0;

    // create constructor to innitilize context and data sent from MainActivity
    public AdapterFish(Context context, List<DataFish> data){
        this.context=context;
        inflater= LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.data=data;
    }

    // Inflate the layout when viewholder created
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab2, parent,false);
        MyHolder holder=new MyHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    // Bind data
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        // Get current position of item in recyclerview to bind data and assign values from list
        MyHolder myHolder= (MyHolder) holder;
        DataFish current=data.get(position);
        myHolder.textmatkul.setText(current.matkul);
        myHolder.textwaktu_batal.setText("Tanggal Batal: " + current.waktu_batal);
        myHolder.textwaktu_pengganti.setText("Tanggal Pengganti: " + current.waktu_pengganti);
        myHolder.textdosen.setText("Nama Dosen: " + current.dosen);
        myHolder.textruang.setText("Ruang: " + current.ruang);
        myHolder.textalasan.setText("Alasan: " + current.alasan);
    }

    // return total item from List
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return data.size();
    }


    class MyHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textmatkul;
        TextView textwaktu_batal;
        TextView textwaktu_pengganti;
        TextView textdosen;
        TextView textruang;
        TextView textalasan;

        // create constructor to get widget reference
        public MyHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textmatkul= (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textmatkul);
            textwaktu_batal = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textwaktu_batal);
            textwaktu_pengganti = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textwaktu_pengganti);
            textdosen = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textdosen);
            textalasan = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textalasan);
            textruang = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textruang);
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of an Fragment containing a Recycler View from [[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html)

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RadioButton;

/**
 * Demonstrates the use of {@link RecyclerView} with a {@link LinearLayoutManager} and a
 * {@link GridLayoutManager}.
 */
public class RecyclerViewFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "RecyclerViewFragment";
    private static final String KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER = "layoutManager";
    private static final int SPAN_COUNT = 2;
    private static final int DATASET_COUNT = 60;

    private enum LayoutManagerType {
        GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER,
        LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER
    }

    protected LayoutManagerType mCurrentLayoutManagerType;

    protected RadioButton mLinearLayoutRadioButton;
    protected RadioButton mGridLayoutRadioButton;

    protected RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    protected CustomAdapter mAdapter;
    protected RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager;
    protected String[] mDataset;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Initialize dataset, this data would usually come from a local content provider or
        // remote server.
        initDataset();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycler_view_frag, container, false);
        rootView.setTag(TAG);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);

        // LinearLayoutManager is used here, this will layout the elements in a similar fashion
        // to the way ListView would layout elements. The RecyclerView.LayoutManager defines how
        // elements are laid out.
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore saved layout manager type.
            mCurrentLayoutManagerType = (LayoutManagerType) savedInstanceState
                    .getSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
        }
        setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(mCurrentLayoutManagerType);

        mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mDataset);
        // Set CustomAdapter as the adapter for RecyclerView.
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        mLinearLayoutRadioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout_rb);
        mLinearLayoutRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
            }
        });

        mGridLayoutRadioButton = (RadioButton) rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_layout_rb);
        mGridLayoutRadioButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER);
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    /**
     * Set RecyclerView's LayoutManager to the one given.
     *
     * @param layoutManagerType Type of layout manager to switch to.
     */
    public void setRecyclerViewLayoutManager(LayoutManagerType layoutManagerType) {
        int scrollPosition = 0;

        // If a layout manager has already been set, get current scroll position.
        if (mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager() != null) {
            scrollPosition = ((LinearLayoutManager) mRecyclerView.getLayoutManager())
                    .findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        }

        switch (layoutManagerType) {
            case GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
                mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), SPAN_COUNT);
                mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.GRID_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
                break;
            case LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER:
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
                break;
            default:
                mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
                mCurrentLayoutManagerType = LayoutManagerType.LINEAR_LAYOUT_MANAGER;
        }

        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        mRecyclerView.scrollToPosition(scrollPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Save currently selected layout manager.
        savedInstanceState.putSerializable(KEY_LAYOUT_MANAGER, mCurrentLayoutManagerType);
        super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    }

    /**
     * Generates Strings for RecyclerView's adapter. This data would usually come
     * from a local content provider or remote server.
     */
    private void initDataset() {
        mDataset = new String[DATASET_COUNT];
        for (int i = 0; i < DATASET_COUNT; i++) {
            mDataset[i] = "This is element #" + i;
        }
    }
}
```

[1](https://developer.android.com/samples/RecyclerView/src/com.example.android.recyclerview/RecyclerViewFragment.html):

So you need a layout with a recyclerview for the fragment, change the ids, add your fishes ArrayList and change this code

mAdapter = new CustomAdapter(mDataset);

to

> `mAdapter = new AdapterFish(getContext(), fishes);`

Then you have a fragment containing a recyclerView